# Anonymous access in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, anonymous-access

How to allow anonymous access in routeconfig in asp.net mvc 5 ?

In routeconfig I've added:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name:"cert",
url:".well-known/acme-challenge")
```

I want to allow anonymous access to `mydomain.com/.well-known/*`

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution.
I have 2 folders named Monitoring & Resources in web layer and I put this code in my web.config and this will work for me

```
<location path="Monitoring">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<location path="Resources">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the tag [AllowAnonymous] on top of the function in your controller you want to allow anonymous access

Comment: I know this solution, thank you. I want to do it in routeconfig, not in controller. I don't have controller ".well-knownController "

Comment: did u find any solution?